# Development only requirements in google cloud function for python

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

We're using the python runtime in Google Cloud and I'm wonder how to specify "Development Only" packages

Typically one would take the setuptools approach with `extras_requires`

```
setup({
    extras_requires={
        'dev': [ 'pytest' ]
    }
})
```

or something to that tune from within the module.

Google's documentation doesn't explicitly mention how to do this, I know they're using Flask to do the actual execution and what not but outside of that I'm lost; don't know if a module can be used.

Is this even possible or would I be better of making different requirements.txt files ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Separate requirements files are the way to go.

If you wanted to make it a little easier for yourself, you could have your "development" requirements file include your production requirements file, e.g. in `development.txt`:

```
pytest
-r requirements.txt
```